# Constructor initialization and assignment

Tags: java, class, object

I'm doing a homework project in my Java class and I have a question. I have two classes:

- Robot
- Grid

`Robot` takes parameters in the constructor and initializes some of its attributes.

I would like to add the `Robot` object that is created, to a two dimensional array of Robot in the constructor but I'm not sure how.

```
public class Robot {
    char name;
    Grid grid;
    int row;
    int col;
    int energyUnits;
    String task;
    int destRow;
    int destCol;
    Robot r;
    Robot[][] roboArr = new Robot[row][col];

    /**
     * Construct a robot and place it in the grid.
     *
     * @param name
     * @param grid
     * @param row
     * @param col
     * @param energyUnits
     */
    public Robot(char name, Grid grid, int row, int col, int energyUnits) {
        this.name = name;
        this.grid = grid;
        this.row = row;
        this.col = col;
        this.energyUnits = energyUnits;
        roboArr = grid.getRoboArr();
        roboArr[row - 1][col - 1] = r;

    }
}
```

Comment: maybe `roboArr` needs to be static else a new one will be created for every `Robot`

Comment: unless you have a method which adds robots to the two dimensional array then you'd have to consider @ScaryWombat suggestion.

Comment: @OusmaneMahyDiaw or move the array out of the `Robot` class

Comment: Please post the code for your `Grid` class. It sounds like that's where your `Robot[][]` array needs to be.